# class appears to be missing from the org.eclipse.OSGI jar?

Tags: java, jar, osgi

I received a new program which I am trying to run.  It uses OSGI and is returning a clasnotfoundexception when it tries to access org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.OSGi.  I'm trying to figure out where this class should be located.

The package came with a jar file named org.eclipse.OSGI.jar (no version numbers).  I checked this jar and it contains the org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core package; but not an OSGi class within it.  I checked the old jar that came packaged with an earlier version of the same application (org.eclipse.OSGI_3.5.1) and it doesn't have the OSGi class either.  I tried looking online and I was able to determine that the older org.eclipse.OSGI_3.3 jar had the OSGi class, but otherwise found no allusion to it.

So can someone clear up my confusion.  Is this class suppose to be part of my 3.5 jar and I'm just too blind to find it, is it part of an entirely different jar, or has it been removed entirely?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is an old launcher class that has been replaced. You should consult the Main-Class manifest header in your org.eclipse.osgi.jar.